# Bad file descriptor after read syscall into mmap allocated buffer in nasm on x86_64

Tags: linux, nasm, x86-64

What's wrong with my [code at github](https://github.com/yaccz/code-samples-asm-cat/tree/mmap)?

- Strace shows the first `read` is ok but second one suddenly `EBADF`.
- Hardcoding `fd` to 3 makes it successfully read and print a file in several chunks.
- Using statically allocated buffer with descriptor still passed through the `fd` binding as shown in the master branch on github makes it also work.
- gdb shows the memory contents at the location of `fd` gets corrupted right after making the first `read` syscall.

Makes me think the memory behind `fd` gets overriden when read into the `buf` happens but I have no idea why.

main.asm:

```
%define     SYS_READ    0
%define     SYS_WRITE   1
%define     SYS_OPEN    2
%define     SYS_MMAP    9
%define     SYS_EXIT    60

%define     PROT_READ   0x1
%define     PROT_WRITE  0x2

%define     MAP_ANONYMOUS   0x20
%define     MAP_PRIVATE     0x02

%define     STD_OUT     1
%define     STD_ERR     2
%define     O_RDONLY    0

%define     CHUNK_SIZE  0x10 ; small to get multiple chunk reads on
                             ; small input
; %define     CHUNK_SIZE  0x1000 ; 4KiB

section .data
    buf     dq  0
    fd      dq  0

    merr_read_failed        db  "read() failed", 0xa
    merr_read_failed_size   equ $-merr_read_failed

    merr_open_failed        db  "open() failed", 0xa
    merr_open_failed_size   equ $-merr_read_failed

section .text
    global  _start

_start:
; unused labels make it easier to set breakpoints in gdb

open_file:
    pop     rdi
    pop     rdi
    ; pop argv[1] into rdi
    pop     rdi
    ; exit if NULL
    cmp     rdi, 0
    je      exit_bad

    ; open argv[1]
    mov     rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov     rsi, O_RDONLY
    syscall

    cmp     rax, 0
    jl      err_open_failed
    mov     [fd], rax
    jmp read_chunk

allocate_buffer:
    mov     rax, SYS_MMAP
    mov     rdi, 0x0
    mov     rsi, CHUNK_SIZE
    mov     rdx, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
    mov     r10, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE
    mov     r8,  -1
    mov     r9,  0
    syscall
    mov     [buf], rax

read_chunk:
    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    mov     rdi, [fd]
    mov     rsi, buf
    mov     rdx, CHUNK_SIZE
    syscall

    ; check for error
    cmp     rax, 0
    jl      err_read_failed
    ; save read byte count to r10
    mov     r10, rax

print_chunk:
    ; if last read yielded 0 bytes, exit.
    ; as 0 signifies an EOF
    cmp     r10, 0
    je      exit_ok

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, STD_OUT
    mov     rsi, buf
    mov     rdx, r10
    syscall

    ; repeat
    jmp     read_chunk

err_open_failed:
    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, STD_ERR
    mov     rsi, merr_open_failed
    mov     rdx, merr_open_failed_size
    syscall

    jmp     exit_bad

err_read_failed:

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, STD_ERR
    mov     rsi, merr_read_failed
    mov     rdx, merr_read_failed_size
    syscall

    jmp     exit_bad

exit_bad:
    mov     rdi, 1
    jmp     exit

exit_ok:
    mov     rdi, 0
    jmp     exit

exit:
    mov     rax, SYS_EXIT
    syscall
```

Makefile:

```
all:

    nasm -g -f elf64 -o main.o main.asm
    ld -o main main.o
```

strace:

```
% strace ./main Makefile
execve("./main", ["./main", "Makefile"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
open("Makefile", O_RDONLY)              = 3
read(3, "all:\n\n\tnasm -g -", 16)      = 16
write(1, "all:\n\n\tnasm -g -", 16all:

        nasm -g -)     = 16
read(544043873, 0x6001e8, 16)           = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
write(2, "read() failed\n", 14read() failed
)         = 14
_exit(1)                                = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

gdb:

```
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function read_chunk:
=> 0x000000000040014c <+0>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400151 <+5>:     mov    0x6001ec,%rdi
   0x0000000000400159 <+13>:    movabs $0x6001e4,%rsi
   0x0000000000400163 <+23>:    mov    $0x10,%edx
   0x0000000000400168 <+28>:    syscall
   0x000000000040016a <+30>:    cmp    $0x0,%rax
   0x000000000040016e <+34>:    jl     0x4001b1 <err_read_failed>
   0x0000000000400170 <+36>:    mov    %rax,%r10
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) p 0x6001ec
$1 = 6291948
(gdb) i r rdi
rdi            0x0      0
(gdb) si
0x0000000000400151 in read_chunk ()
(gdb) i r rdi
rdi            0x0      0
(gdb) p 0x6001ec
$2 = 6291948
(gdb) x 0x6001ec
0x6001ec <fd>:  0x00000003
(gdb) si
0x0000000000400159 in read_chunk ()
(gdb) x 0x6001ec
0x6001ec <fd>:  0x00000003
(gdb) si
0x0000000000400163 in read_chunk ()
(gdb) x 0x6001ec
0x6001ec <fd>:  0x00000003
(gdb) si
0x0000000000400168 in read_chunk ()
(gdb) x 0x6001ec
0x6001ec <fd>:  0x00000003
(gdb) si
0x000000000040016a in read_chunk ()
(gdb) x 0x6001ec
0x6001ec <fd>:  0x206d7361
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function read_chunk:
   0x000000000040014c <+0>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400151 <+5>:     mov    0x6001ec,%rdi
   0x0000000000400159 <+13>:    movabs $0x6001e4,%rsi
   0x0000000000400163 <+23>:    mov    $0x10,%edx
   0x0000000000400168 <+28>:    syscall
=> 0x000000000040016a <+30>:    cmp    $0x0,%rax
   0x000000000040016e <+34>:    jl     0x4001b1 <err_read_failed>
   0x0000000000400170 <+36>:    mov    %rax,%r10
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Comment: What do you mean? 1. I could probably store it in register and side-step the problem (as with using static buffer) but that won't make me understand what is wrong. In larger program I won't be able to leave stuff only in registers. 2 heap can be accessed only by pointer, right? 3. I could push it on stack but then see 1.

Comment: `mov buf, rax` doesn't compile. I think `[p]` in nasm generally means the dereferenced p, the value at address p. While `p` is the address. But I don't grok how exactly this works yet.

Comment: "`buf` it the address, `[buf]` is its contents. `[buf]` should be the address" does not compute. `buf` is the address, `[buf]` the first byte pointed at by `buf`, which is 0 (guaranteed by mmap). Therefore read into `[buf]` instead of `buf` won't work not even once.

Comment: I was right. The problem is bad indirection in the code. Read into `[buf]` works after you let the mmap syscall happen. Posted that as an answer. Thanks for an interesting challenge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the `allocate_buffer` instructions and you use bad level of indirection in `read_chunk` and `print_chunk`. With this patch applied, your code works:

```
diff --git a/main.asm b/main.asm
index c9c98e4..8c44223 100644
--- a/main.asm
+++ b/main.asm
@@ -51,7 +51,6 @@ open_file:
     cmp     rax, 0
     jl      err_open_failed
     mov     [fd], rax
-    jmp read_chunk

 allocate_buffer:
     mov     rax, SYS_MMAP
@@ -67,7 +66,7 @@ allocate_buffer:
 read_chunk:
     mov     rax, SYS_READ
     mov     rdi, [fd]
-    mov     rsi, buf
+    mov     rsi, [buf]
     mov     rdx, CHUNK_SIZE
     syscall

@@ -85,7 +84,7 @@ print_chunk:

     mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
     mov     rdi, STD_OUT
-    mov     rsi, buf
+    mov     rsi, [buf]
     mov     rdx, r10
     syscall
```

The `jmp` removal lets `allocate_buffer` instructions be executed, the other two changes make the syscalls use the address of allocated memory instead of address, where this address is stored.

What happened?

You did not allocate the memory for the buffer as your strace shows (no mmap syscall is performed). The `buf` is address of 8 bytes of memory (`dq`) in the data section, which is initialized to 0 when the program starts.

Your code reads into `buf` directly and thus overwrites contents of the data section, including `fp` which is right after `buf`. Second iteration of `read_chunk` finds a strange value in `fp` and crashes.

When you skipped the allocation and changed your code to read into `[buf]`, as we discussed in the comments, you read into address 0, which crashed your program even earlier from now obvious reasons.

Comment: Oh crap. I forgot to remove the jmp. Everything I posted applied to the code without the jmp. Only trying the `[buf]` instead of `buf` did not work for me because of this forgotten jmp. Thank you.